# Setting values to Common DTO

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, dto

I have the below code of the entity classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Date_col")
    private String dt;

    @Column(name = "Col_A")
    private String  colA;
    }

    @Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Date_col")
    private String dt;

    @Column(name = "Col_B")
    private String  colA;
    }
```

I have omitted the getters and setters for brevity .
I have created separate repositories  and DTO  for both entity A and entity B.

Separate reposity

```
List<Adto> findAll ( String dt) ;
List<Bdto> findAll ( String dt) ;
```

Adto and Bdto have same fields as their corresponding  entities .I have omitted them for brevity .

I have created one more DTO 
How can i set the values from Adto and Bdto to CommonDto in my Service implementation?

```
public class CommonDto {


    private List<Adto>    bdto ;

    private List<Bdto>    bdto ;
//I have omitted the getters and setters for brevity .


    }
```

Comment: you need a service where you'll inject AdtoRepository and BdtoRepository then you will do some think like commonDto.setAdto(adtoRepository.findAll()) and commonDto.setBdto(bdtoRepository.findAll()) 
Is that what you need ?

Comment: i need to set only selected fields not all